# PHP - Header Redirect - passing variable

Tags: php

I have looked through loads of pages on here and cannot find an answer. I am looking to redirect a user. The code I am using does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
header('Location: home.php?username='<?php echo $user['username'];?>);
```

Comment: Does not work is not a lot of help. What errors do you get?

Comment: You seem to have php tags withing php?? Or is the above supposed to be javascript??

Comment: sorry for not being clear

Comment: See Emily's answer below. An additional point: I'm guessing you are developing without error reporting enabled - you are shooting in the dark if you are doing this. It's useful and good practice to show all the helpful notices, warnings and errors when you're coding. Set this at the top of your script *when developing*: `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);`. Have a read here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. Also, very importantly, make sure you *disable* `error_reporting` and `display_errors` when putting your site live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?php` tags don't work like that for strings. Use `.` instead:

`header('Location: home.php?username=' . $user['username']);`

Make sure you call `exit();` right after as well :) x

Comment: Snap! Beat me to it :)

Comment: Glad we could help :) x

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a syntax error:

```
header('Location: home.php?username='<?php echo $user['username'];?>);
```

Try this instead:

```
header('Location: home.php?username=' . $user['username']);
```